# How to Fix Ductwork that I Crushed?

Tags: ducts

I stumbled off of a step ladder and crushed this ductwork. It's in a bathroom and runs along the floor on a concrete slab between joists. The house is 50 yrs old. The ductwork looks like it's galvanized. How do I repair or replace it? The end of the run continues under a wall. Is there a seam on the bottom? If so, I probably ruptured it. [image] [image]
[image]

Comment: where does it disappear to on the left?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like common 3 1/4" x 14" rectangular tin vent pipe, you should be able to buy it at any good plumbing shop. It sometimes comes with a locking seam along one edge but HVAC professionals often buy non-seamed pieces of various lengths.

You may be able to beat that back into shape and use *listed* duct tape to patch it up. If not you will need to find the next upstream connection and replace the whole length.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Not sure what would be the best way to beat it back into shape. Maybe remove the drywall and the 90 degree turn, so as to access it straight on?... Unfortunately, I don't have access to the next upstream connection as it is under the next room...Would it be possible to cut out the bent part and connect it to a new one somehow? I don't have much room in which to operate as there are joists on either side of the duct.