# How to fix a crushed A/C duct

Tags: air-conditioning, ducts, central-air

One of my kids got into the attic and walked all over my 7" aluminum (?) round ducts. See the picture below. I found [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100285/how-to-fix-ductwork-that-i-crushed), but that's a different type of duct.

My idea is to drill a hole and use a wine corkscrew to pull it back up while squeezing from the sides. Then duct tape to cover up the hole.
[image]

Comment: Probably quicker to purchase a replacement section. Then consider how to stop the kids playing up there.

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer. I'd be very interested in hearing about which solution you've pursued =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm amazed that the child did not fall through the ceiling.

Odds are high that this is actually a 6" duct but the insulation makes it thicker. Also, typical material is galvanized steel; likely 28 or 26 gauge, or 30 if the contractor cheaped out.

I assume you thought it's aluminum because that's typical for dryer vents. Aluminum is more expensive but it's smoother at a microscopic level which is important so that lint doesn't get caught on the walls. It also resists corrosion which is important for all the humid air being pumped through a dryer vent.

I would slice away the insulation with a utility knife as shown below and check the extent of the damage.

[image]

Anyways, once you see the actual damage then you can decide how to proceed. I would cut the ductwork at a fairly round section using tin snips, cut some new ductwork to size, crimp where appropriate, fasten with sheet metal (zip) screws, seal with tape, and then tape the insulation back into place.

Assuming that you already own at least a drill then the tools+material cost should be about $100. An HVAC contractor would likely want $300.

---

As for the wine corkscrew idea, I don't like it but you could give it a try. At worst you would realize that you need to properly fix the issue as outlined above.

If it works then its very likely you'd need to apply this method in 3-5 places based on the perceived length in your picture. I would start in the least crushed area and move towards the center slowly. There is very likely a hard crease in your round duct so if you try to tackle the middle right away then you'll make things worse.

Believe it or not, duct tape is not approved for ductwork. You need a proper "foil tape" or even mastic sealant would be fine for such a small hole. I personally really really like Nashua Foilmastic Tape.